# Dynamic Paint not showing in Render

Tags: materials, shader-nodes, vertex-colors, dynamic-paint, roughness

I am follwing this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_hBPKqjgy6E) to simulate rain drops falling onto the ground. The drop should make the ground wet. Therefore I am using dynamic paint. In the material the wetmap is plugged into the roughness input. The problem is that the surface only appears wet in the rendered preview but NOT in the render itself. I didn't find anything that's disabled for render. Thank you for your help!

[Blendfile](https://we.tl/t-Itwnkyal6J)

[image: Render Preview]

[image: Render]

[image: Screenshot1]

[image: Screenshot2]

[image: Screenshot3]

[image: Screenshot4]

Comment: We're unlikely to be able to help you without more information. Can you add screen shots that show more data, or, better yet, a Blend file that shows the problem?  It doesn't have to be your final Blend file, just a subset that has the issue.

Comment: @MartyFouts Hello Marty, thanks for the hint. I have attached some more screenshots and the blend file is attached as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your blend file, there are some settings messed up. The animation starts and ends at frame 76 (=1 frame only). And the *Dynamic Paint* is simulated for frames 1 to 500... 
 Also, Blender has now and then some issues regarding *particles* and *Dynamic Paint*. Sometimes the viewport is not up to date. I've just had a wet ground at frame 1 when no particle had hit the ground yet. In the render it was dry. But that's not the reason for your problem.

**The reason for your described problem is the different *Subdivision Surface* levels** for *Viewport* (`1`) and *Render* (`2`). The *Dynamic Paint* is stored in the vertices. Level 1 increases your vertice count from 207,760 to 830,488. For these vertices the physics are baked. When you render an image Blender will do another subdivide which results in over 3.3 million vertices. But for these vertices, there is no baked data and no *Dynamic Paint* is shown. The same happens if you bake the physics and then lower the level.

It works when you

- set the levels of the *Subdivision Surface* modifier to the same value, e.g. `1` and `1` for *Viewport* and *Render*
- set the animation *start* to `1` and *end* to `80`
- also set the *Dynamic Paint* cache to `1` and `80`.
- go to frame 1 and (re-)bake the *Particles*, then the *Dynamic Paint*

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Exact same issue using Blender 3.3, was using a subdivision modifier on my surface with different viewport/render quantities that prevented the baked simulation from rendering. Is this an implementation bug that it doesn't pre-bake both the viewport AND the render subdivision?